# How Can I install Ubuntu 13.04, preferably without creating a new partition on my 64 bit Windows 8 UEFI Acer Aspire E1-571 laptop?

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows-8, uefi, acer

I realise this might be a duplicate I am asking because I can't find any questions so far that address this question but I wouldn't imagine it'd be too rare. I accidentally deleted Windows 8 last time I tried to install Ubuntu on my laptop so I would like to be guided through this please. I love Ubuntu, don't mind Windows 8 and it'd be just great if they could coexist in peace and harmony on my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of not creating a new partition on your existing disk, I know of only three solutions:

- **Install in a virtual machine** -- You can use VirtualBox, VMWare, or similar software to install Ubuntu in a virtual environment under Windows. This usually works well, but there may be a performance penalty.
- **Install on a separate disk** -- You can install Ubuntu on a separate hard disk. (For a laptop, that's likely to be an external disk, but some laptops have bays for two hard disks.)
- **Use WUBI** -- This installs Ubuntu in a file on the Windows filesystem. This option, however, works only on BIOS-based computers, and IIRC, the developers are moving away from WUBI. Thus, it's not a real option for you unless your "UEFI" tag is a mistake, and even then it might not work in another release or two.

As a practical matter, your best solution is to be prepared with a complete system backup and a plan to restore it; then familiarize yourself with the installation procedure and the meanings of all the options, so that you can navigate it to do what you want. Unfortunately, the step-by-step guides that are so popular today do little to provide the sort of understanding that's needed for making meaningful decisions about your installation.

Comment: Rod, OP is asking about 13.04 and [Wubi isn't supported for this version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer). You may want to edit your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to select "Install Alongside Windows 8" during the installation process, and Ubuntu will automatically be installed next to Windows 8 without deleting it. Just make sure that you select this option when you get to the part where you set up partitions. Should be a simple two clicks, and it won't delete Windows.

Comment: Have you actually tried what you've suggested?